# Best comparison operator when using COUNT in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, comparison-operators

Doing a mysqli query and COUNTing the results, is there a preferred comparison operator & string enquoting to use?

For example

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_color` = '{$color}'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($result['COUNT(`user_id`)'] != 0){
 -- then do something....
```

My question is, what are the implications of using:

```
if ($result['COUNT(`user_id`)'] != '0'){
```

versus

```
if ($result['COUNT(`user_id`)'] != 0){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are same, php takes care of string and number.

Internally functionality of php interpreter: If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, a little confirmation always makes your code feel warm & fuzzy...

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be:

```
... "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as user_count ..." ...

if ($result['user_count'])
```

`0` and `'0'` are both `false` in PHP, so this does what you're looking for very concisely.

Comment: I *knew* about the False value, just never thought of using it in this sense. Actually I just grabbed this chuck of code, several others I use actually compare to *something*. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
<?php

0=='0'; // true
0==='0' // false

0!='0'; // false
0!=='0'; // true

?>
```

in your case it doesn't matter since you are only using one `=`

Comment: thanks. But I think deceze and Madan caught the drift of what I was thinking. It was more a what does **$result['COUNT(`user_id`)']** prefer to compare to.

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli_fetch_row instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc.

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
if ($result[0] != 0){
    // your code
}
```